# If statement to use <a href one> else use <a href two>

Tags: php, html, href

What I'm trying to do is that any form with the $id that is less than 50 to use a certain A href else use another A HREF. This is what I have so far but I have no idea how to include it since it has php with in the HREF. How can I make this work. Thanks in advance.

```
</td>        
<td>    
<?php if($id <= 50) { 
    <a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&***template***=true"><?=$row[software]?></a> 
}
else  { 
    <a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&***modify***=true"><?=$row[software]?></a> 
} 
?>
</td>
```

Comment: For some reason is not reading or not liking the code, I tested all examples and it will link to the first href even if the $id is greater than 50, I even switch the <= to >= and it linked only to the second href even if less or greater. I think there is something else making do this. But really appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

```
<td>    
<?php if($id <= 50): ?>
    <a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&***template***=true"><?=$row[software]?></a> 
<?php else: ?> 
    <a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&***modify***=true"><?=$row[software]?></a> 
<?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to do this would be to just use an if statement on the part of the anchor tag that **changes** (the modify/template bit):

```
<a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&<?=$id <= 50 ? 'template' : 'modify'?>=true"><?=$row[software]?></a>
```

You can put this anywhere in a page that is parsed by PHP (doesn't matter that there's inline PHP in your HTML.

Exit PHP like this (easy enough - in your case you don't need to edit really, you just wrap the top example here in your `<td>` tags):

```
?>
<a href="<?=$row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?=$row[id]?>&form=<?=$row[form_type]?>&<?=$id <= 50 ? 'template' : 'modify'?>=true"><?=$row[software]?></a>
<?php
```

... or:

```
$action = $id <= 50 ? 'template' : 'modify';
echo '<a href="' . $row['form_type'] . '.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&form=' . $row['form_tyoe'] . '&' . $action . '=true">' . $row['software'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($id <= 50) {
    echo '<a href="' . $row['form_type'] . '.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&form='. $row['form_type']. '&***template***=true">' . $row['software'] . '</a>';
} else {
 echo '<a href="'. $row['form_type'] . '.php?id='. $row['id'] . '&form='. $row['form_type'] . '&***modify***=true">'. $row['software'] . '</a>';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is your friend.

```
<td>
<?php
$frame = "<a href="%s.php?id=%s&form=%s&%s=true">%s</a>";
if($id <= 50) {
  printf($frame, $row[form_type], $row[id], $row[form_type], '***template***', $row[software]);
} else  { 
  printf($frame, $row[form_type], $row[id], $row[form_type], '***modify***', $row[software]);
} 
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
</td>
<td>    
<?php 
    if($id <= 50) { 
        echo '<a href="'.$row[form_type].'.php?id='.$row[id].'&form='.$row[form_type].'&***template***=true">'.$row[software].'</a>';
    } else  { 
        echo '<a href="'.$row[form_type].'.php?id='.$row[id].'&form='.$row[form_type].'&***modify***=true">'.$row[software].'</a>';
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the short tags `<?=?>`, this is considered bad practice.

Secondly, you may use this:

```
</td>        
<td>    
  <?php if($id <= 50) { ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo $row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>&form=<?php echo $row[form_type]?>&***template***=true"><?php echo $row[software]?></a> 
       <?php } else  { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $row[form_type]?>.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>&form=<?php echo $row[form_type]?>&***modify***=true"><?php echo $row[software]?></a> 
  <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Short tags are enabled by default in PHP >= 5.4, so I don't think it's bad practice at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Nevertheless, they are the source of all problems if you decide to move your program to a server with PHP < 5.4. Also, see this answer for further explanation: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/151694